# Find fights for a fighter in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, relationship

I have two models: `Fight` and `Fighter`. My `Fight` model has two `belongsTo` relationships:

```
<?php
class Fight extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'FighterA' => array(
            'className' => 'Fighter',
            'joinTable' => 'fighters',
            'foreignKey' => 'fighter_a_id'
        ),
        'FighterB' => array(
            'className' => 'Fighter',
            'joinTable' => 'fighters',
            'foreignKey' => 'fighter_b_id'
        )
    );
}
```

This is so I can set two fighters that participate in a fight. However, I’m having difficulty working out how to set the other side of the relationship, in my `Fighter` model.

I know I want to find all fights where either the `fighter_a_id` or `fighter_b_id` column equals the fighter ID, but having trouble translating this to a relationship in my model.

I’ve tried:

```
<?php
class Fighter extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Fight' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    'Fight.fighter_a_id' => 'Fighter.id',
                    'Fight.fighter_b_id' => 'Fighter.id'
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

But CakePHP throws an error, where it is still trying to query the (non-existent) `fighter_id` it’s automatically generating, combining the generated `WHERE` clause with the `OR` clause I‘ve specified above.

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Fight.fighter_id' in 'field list'

And the generated SQL statement:

> `SELECT Fight.id, Fight.fighter_a_id, Fight.fighter_b_id, Fight.event_id, Fight.weight_division_id, Fight.rounds, Fight.rounds_length, Fight.winner, Fight.winning_round, Fight.winning_time, Fight.win_method, Fight.fighter_id FROM fights AS Fight WHERE ((Fight.fighter_a_id = 'Fighter.id') OR (Fight.fighter_b_id = 'Fighter.id')) AND Fight.fighter_id = (1)`

When finding records from the `fighters` table, I’d like to also list related `Fight` models (in chronological order, but that’s handled in another column left out as it’s unrelated to this issue).

Comment: Your setup is incorrect. You should be using HABTM (hasAndBelongsToMany) to join your Fighters to their Fights. Then you can store the extra data in the join table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the conditions in the Fighter model. Make the model simple:

```
class Fighter extends AppModel {
  var $hasMany = 'Fight';
}
```

Then in you controller do the logic and workout the fights for the fighter:

```
public function index($id = null) {     
        if (!$id) {
        }
        $fighter = $this->Fighter->findById($id);
        if (!$project) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid fighter'));
        } else {
            $this->set('fighter', $fighter);

            $fights = $this->Fighter->Fight->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                'Fight.fighter_a_id' => 'Fighter.id',
                'Fight.fighter_b_id' => 'Fighter.id'
            )
        )));
            $this->set('fights', $fights);
        }
}
```

Comment: If you re-read my question, the `fighter_id` column _doesn’t_ exist in the `fights` table; there’s two columns that relate to a fighter: `fighter_a_id` and `fighter_b_id`. These represent the two fighters participating in a fight.

Comment: sorry I missed that. In that case the relationship you are creating is not suitable. By defining 'belongsTo' you are creating a one to many relationship. Because you have more than one fighter per fight, and more than one fight per fighter, I suggest that you look at creating a  HABTM (Has and belongs to many) relationship. Check this out for more info: http://www.learncomputer.com/cakephp-relationships/

Comment: I don’t really want to define a HABTM relationship, as I know they’ll **always** be two fighters (a fighter and an opponent) in a fight.

Comment: I edited my answer. Have a look at the line  $fights = $this->Fighter->Fight->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                'Fight.fighter_a_id' => 'Fighter.id',
                'Fight.fighter_b_id' => 'Fighter.id'
            )
        )));

Comment: Hmm, seems this is the only reason to go. I was trying to use these types of conditions directly in the model, so I didn’t have to construct my find operations manually in my controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add an extra table that will hold which Fighters belongs to a Fight, and limit that to 2 records per fight. Or, you have to have two belongsTo associations.

With two belongsTo associations the Fight model would look like this.

```
class Fighter extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'FightA' => array(
             'className'=>'Fight',
             'foreignKey'=>'fighter_a_id'
        ),
        'FightB' => array(
             'className'=>'Fight',
             'foreignKey'=>'fighter_b_id'
        )
    );
}
```

You could then merge the two associated results of FightA and FightB into a single list called Fight. Do this in the controller or maybe the afterFind callback in the model.

I think it can be done something like this.

```
 $fights = $this->Fighter->find(....);
 $fights['Fighter']['Fight'] = $fights['Fighter']['FightA']+$fights['Fighter']['FightB'];
```

The other approach is to add another table to associate Fighters with a Fight. You could call this table fight_members.

It would be a simple table.

```
CREATE  TABLE `fight_members` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `fighter_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `fight_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

You can now find all the Fights a Fighter belongs to.

```
class Fighter extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('FightMember');
}

class Fight extends AppModel {
     public $hasMany = array('FightMember');
);

class FightMember extends AppModel {
     public $belongsTo=array('Fight','Fighter');
);
```